VS Code Stuck temporar– Clicking Outside Temporarily Fixes It, but It Keeps Returning
I'm experiencing a strange issue with Visual Studio Code where it often freezes or gets stuck, and I can temporarily fix it by either using Alt+Tab, pressing the Windows key, or even clicking outside of VS Code and then clicking back in. However, after a short while, the issue reappears.
Some specific symptoms I’ve noticed:

Sometimes only part of my code scrolls smoothly while the rest of the code display gets stuck or lags.
Occasionally, I’m unable to click anywhere inside VS Code when it’s frozen, as if the editor becomes unresponsive.

I've tried some common fixes, but nothing seems to provide a lasting solution. Has anyone else experienced this or found a solution?
I tried switching windows using Alt+Tab, pressing the Windows key, or clicking outside of VS Code and then clicking back in. Each of these actions temporarily resolves the freeze, but the issue returns after a short time.
I also tried some basic troubleshooting steps like restarting VS Code, checking for updates, and disabling some extensions to see if they were causing the issue. and also try to reinstall vsCode but None of these provided a lasting fix.
